# How to arrange the images in an array starting from index 1 in Objective C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have some buttons in my view, which contain images in them to make it look like a thumbnail view. If tapped on the button, based on the button tag, i have to retrieve the image from the database and show it in fullscreen. I am storing the button tag's value(***integer*** *which starts from zero*) in a string and in the database, am passing this string value to retrieve my image. Problem is, since the button tag value starts from zero, the string value can't retrieve image from database, because the id value in the database starts from 1. So,  i have to give **tag+1** to make the string value start from 1. So now, if i tap on button 1, based on the button tag, the string value will also be 1 and the image stored in **id1** will be retrieved from the database. But since i am storing the images from the database in an array, the images in an array would start from ***index zero***. So if i tap on button 1, the next ie.2nd image(index 1) gets called. Tap on button 2, 3rd image(index 2) gets called and so on...

So i want to know whether we can arrange the images in an array ***starting from index 1*** and not from index zero?

This is my code, 
http://pastie.org/8163171

Comment: "I have 100 * 100 buttons in my view" - erm?

Comment: I meant the button's cross section to make it look like a thumbnail view.

Comment: Why dont you retrieve the images from the array based on the tag? Tag is same as the index of the array.

Comment: Yah,..but id value in the database starts from 1 ryt?

Comment: You are able to retrieve them correctly, right? Now the images are stored in an array. Lets say you want to retrieve the image, corresponding to first button whose tag is 0, you do,
[array objectAtIndex:button.tag];

Comment: It's over **9,000**!!!!! (buttons)

Answer (score 0):

> For doing like that add one default value to that images array at
>   index 0,after that your values are followed by the that object.and in
>   your case i think no need to do like this when you want to fetch the
>   data at that time simply decrement one value means use tag-1

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But if i give tag-1, the string value would be also be -1 and from database, i cant retrieve the id value ryt?

Comment: when this'l haappend while retrieving first object?

Comment: Suppose if i just give "tag", the value of the string would be zero and so, from database there is no id 0 . So, if i click on button 1, the application will crash

Comment: while retrieving the data base value you can add +1 .

Comment: Whichever image am getting from the database, am storing that image in an array and so, if i write this line of code, 
[wallPaperButton setImage:[blaukypath objectAtIndex:i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
the image index will start from zero and not from 1.

Comment: if u write like  [wallPaperButton setImage:[blaukypath objectAtIndex:i-1] forState:UIControlStateNormal]; then it'l work na?replce i with i-1

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33883/discussion-between-umesh-kumar-and-sunny)

Comment: @Umesh Kumar:have u got the solution?